# Updating state with Hook causes infinite loop within function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'd like to understand better why updating the state within a function that I call directly below is causing the function to run in a infinite loop.

I understand that I should be using "useEffect" if I want to update the state immediately after it mounts, but I want to know the mechanics behind why this infinite loop is happening.

I have tried removing the function call that updates the state, and I can see that it no longer runs in an infinite loop.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState();
  const getSheetData = text => {
    setTasks(text);
    console.log(text);
  };
  getSheetData("time");
```

If "setTasks(text)" is removed, there is no longer an infinite loop present.

Answer (score 2):

When state is updated, the component re-renders. So, in your case, you are updating the state, which re-renders the component, and then you are updating again - causing an infinite loop.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  getSheetData("time")
}, [])
```

The [] as the second argument means the dependency array is empty - causing it to happen only once (similar to componentDidMount())

Comment: That was the missing piece for me. I was strangely only thinking the return was getting re-rendered but that obviously wouldn't be possible without re-rendering the entire component. 

I appreciate the quick answer. Thanks!